How many color information loss if I iterate all hue and value while keep saturation constant?
If I keep saturation 100%, then I branched iteration of hue from 0 to 359 and value from 0% to 100% to convert HSV to RGB, how many color that I loss such information?
RGB has combination 2^24

If we assume that you iterate with reasonable small steps, then your question basically is, how many RGB-colors have a saturation of 100%.
So we can have a look at the computation of the $S$-component of HSV:
Let $\max=\max(r,b,g)$ be the maximal component of the rbg-values and let $\min=\min(r,b,g)$ be the minimum. Then the saturation is given by:
$$S=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}0&\text{if }\max=0\\\frac{\max-\min}{\max}&\text{else}\end{array} \right.$$
This means, $S=100\%$ can only be reached, if $\min=0$. This leads to counting the colors, where at least one (but not all) rgb-components are 0:
$$\begin{align}
n &= 1\cdot 2^{16} & \small{r=0}\\
&+255\cdot 1\cdot 2^8 & \small{r>0, g=0}\\
&+255^2 \cdot 1 & \small{r>0, g>0, b=0}\\
&-1 & \small{r=g=b=0}\\
&= 3\cdot(2^{16}-2^8)
\end{align}$$
These are about 1.17% of all colors
